# Can an offset:ed 9VAC be used as a normal 9VAC source?

Tags: voltage, pwm

Consider a normal sine curve for 9VAC; top hits +9, bottom hits -9V.

Then consider the same curve that's offset:ed, or "lifted", by a DC-voltage; top hits +18V, bottom hits 0V.

The second curve is produced by PWM from a DC-source, therefore there are no negative voltages.

Question: if one wants to use the lifted curve in a 9VAC-application (i.e. feed it), how can one "lower" it again? That is, putting the center back at 0V.

Is this at all possible?

Comment: Voltage is relative. Think of option B as option A being from -9 to 9 volts but without an extra pin for the centre 0V.

Comment: 9VAC will have a peak of about 12.7 volts because, without any conditioning statement to the contrary, a voltage is regarded as RMS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if one wants to use the lifted curve in a 9VAC-application (i.e. feed
>   it), how can one "lower" it again? That is, putting the center back at
>   0V

If you want to convert a 0 to 18 volt sinewave to a sinewave that has an average value of zero volts then feed it through a high pass filter formed by a series capacitor and resistor to 0 volts.

If you want to draw power from it you need to choose the value of capacitor to be somewhat higher than if it were just a signal but, in all cases, make the RC time constant suitable to pass the signal without significant attenuation.

[image]

You can also achieve the same with an inductor and resistor: -

[image]

However, it will be more economical to use the RC network and there will be less chance of inductor core saturation with dc running through the inductor.